# In R, plm regression with possible constant dummies

Tags: r, plm

I'm trying to create a basic plm regression. The problem is that I am trying to run thousands of different regressions (one for each county in the US) at once, so I can't customize each one.
The command I want to run looks like this:

```
pm1 <- plm(y~x+unemploymentRate+rnetmig+percentageAbove65+xmas+xmas1+newyears+valentines+easter+thanksgiving+mothersday+halloween+superbowl+julyfourth,index=c("upc","week_end"),data=counties[[c]])
```

The variables from xmas to julyfourth are all dummies, and everything else is not.
The following runs fine for all counties:

```
pm2 <- plm(y~x+unemploymentRate+rnetmig+percentageAbove65,index=c("upc","week_end"),data=counties[[c]])
```

But once I add the dummies, in that first plm, I get this error or a similar one:

```
series fips_state_code, xfips_county_code, xupc_ver_uc, xSTNAME, xCTYNAME, xxmas, xnewyears, xvalentines, xeaster, xsuperbowl, xjulyfourth are constants and have been removed
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'xmas' not found
```

I realized that this is because each of the dummies only varies in some of the counties. In this case, xmas was always 0 so it caused the regression to crash.
Is there a way to instruct plm to only include those regressors that are NOT constants, rather than receive this error? I can't manually do each regression because there are thousands. I also cannot reasonably create "if" statements for each dummy variable because likely I will soon be adding many more.
Does anyone know a command that will do this for me?
Thanks for much in advance.

Comment: Use `tryCatch` inside the loop to handle the error and continue the loop. See [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Exceptions-Debugging.html) for further details.